# Putting specific subtitle on tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

I want to put the "(2+2+2=6 points)" into a little subtitle card below the tcolorbox.

Here is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{before skip=16pt, after skip=12pt,breakable, fonttitle=\Large,colback=gray!20,colframe=red!30!black, title=#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Problem 1: blabla}blablabla \vspace*{1cm}
\begin{flushright}
(2+2+2=6 points)
\par\end{flushright}

\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

What I want it to look like I tried to visualise here (the background can also be in dark red, I just used paint real quick):

[image]

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{before skip=16pt, after skip=0pt,breakable, fonttitle=\Large,colback=gray!20,colframe=red!30!black, title=#1}

\newenvironment{myfullbox}[2][]{\def\Arg{#1}\begin{mybox}{#2}}{\end{mybox}\ifx\Arg\empty\relax\else\vspace{-12pt}\par\begin{flushright}\begin{minipage}[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{0.4\linewidth}\begin{mybox}{}\Arg\end{mybox}\end{minipage}\end{flushright}\fi\vspace{12pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{myfullbox}[(2+2+2=6 points)]{Problem 1: blabla}blablabla \vspace*{1cm}
\end{myfullbox}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: The second box could have completely different settings via another "tcolorbox"

Comment: +1 but it seems strange to define `mybox` and then to use `newenvironment`.... can it be done all in one go using existing mechanisms from the `tcolorbox` package?....

Comment: @cmhughes ... I don't really use tcolorbox... and I see two boxes there ... So, the easy thinking is a way like this ... Thanks for your comment ... Of course if you add an answer with one tcolorbox, I am going to upvote...

Comment: Oof. This seems really complex. I was thinking about using the \tcbsubtitle command. It is described in the manual on p.21 but I can't get my desired box as described above. Do you think there is a way to use this command?

Answer (score 1):

It can easily be done with an `overlay`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{before skip=16pt, after skip=12pt,breakable, 
fonttitle=\Large,colback=gray!20,colframe=red!30!black,enhanced,
enlarge bottom by=1.5em,title=#1,overlay={\node[anchor=north east,
 draw,very thick,red!30!black,fill=gray!20] at ([xshift=-3pt]frame.south east){(#2)};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Problem 1: blabla}{2+2+2=6 points}
blablabla \vspace*{1cm}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that I set the frame color and the fill color of the node containing the points explicitly. However, If that bothers you, one can easily inherit it from the "mother box".

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable,skins}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{before skip=16pt, after skip=12pt,breakable, 
fonttitle=\Large,colback=gray!20,colframe=red!30!black,enhanced,
enlarge bottom by=1.5em,title=#1,overlay={\node[anchor=north east,
 draw,very thick,tcbcolframe,fill=tcbcolback] at ([xshift=-3pt]frame.south east){(#2)};}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}{Problem 1: blabla}{2+2+2=6 points}
blablabla \vspace*{1cm}
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```